# using unary operator in function determined by Swift enum

Tags: swift

Would like to use an enum and depending on the enum value, perform addition or subtraction, using Swift (v3).

This so I can avoid something like:

```
enum Direction {
  case east, west
}

func example(direction:Direction, _ left: Int, _ right: Int) -> Int {
  // ...

  // next a bunch of functions that depending on the direction add or subtract two values

  // would like to avoid the following repetitive evaluations:
  let oneOfTheCalculations = direction == .east ? left + right : left - right
  //let anotherCalculation = direction == .east ? left + 2*right : left - 2*right
  //let andAnotherOne      = direction == .east ? left + 3*right : left - 3*right
  //...

  return oneOfTheCalculations
}

print("\( example(direction:.east, 4, 3) )") // 7
print("\( example(direction:.west, 4, 3) )") // 1
```

I assume it is possible to make the operator function part of the enum so I don't need the comparison to determine what operation to perform.

Maybe along the lines of e.g.:

```
func doit(_ myOperator:(Int,Int)->Int, _ left:Int, _ right:Int) -> Int {
    return myOperator(left,right)
}

print("\( doit(+,4,3) )")
print("\( doit(-,4,3) )")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method to you `enum` which returns a binary operation depending on the `case` of `self`.

```
enum Direction {
    case east, west

    func combine<T: IntegerArithmetic>() -> (T, T) -> T {
        switch self {
        case .east: return (+)
        case .west: return (-)
        }
    }
}

func example(direction: Direction, _ left: Int, _ right: Int) -> Int {
    let oneOfTheCalculations = direction.combine()(left, right)
    let anotherCalculation = direction.combine()(left, 2*right)
    let andAnotherOne      = direction.combine()(left, 3*right)
    //...

    return oneOfTheCalculations
}
```

Or, simply let the `enum` method perform the combining evaluation itself, returning only the result:

```
enum Direction {
    case east, west

    func combine<T: IntegerArithmetic>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) -> T {
        switch self {
        case .east: return lhs + rhs
        case .west: return lhs - rhs
        }
    }
}

func example(direction: Direction, _ left: Int, _ right: Int) -> Int {
    let oneOfTheCalculations = direction.combine(left, right)
    let anotherCalculation = direction.combine(left, 2*right)
    let andAnotherOne      = direction.combine(left, 3*right)
    //...

    return oneOfTheCalculations
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
let sign = direction == .east ? 1 : -1
let oneOfTheCalculations = left + sign * right
let anotherCalculation = left + sign * 2 * right
```

Adding a negative number is the same as subtracting a positive number.

Comment: Indeed the simplest solution for this particular example. Was looking for a enum function, so marked that one as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Direction {
    case east, west

    func op<T: IntegerArithmetic>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) -> T {
        switch self {
        case .east:
            return lhs + rhs
        case .west:
            return lhs - rhs
        }
    }
}

Direction.east.op(4, 3) // 7
Direction.west.op(4, 3) // 1
```